# Binary Search Tree Insert Unsorted Array

Tags: arrays, insert, binary-search-tree

I have a problem trying to insert elements on my BST given an unsorted array. The output gives me a segmentation fault, but I can't pinpoint the location of my error. I'm pretty sure that something is wrong with my insert, but I'm not sure what. If anyone can give me insight that would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct BST{
    BST* left;
    BST* right;
    int data;
};

BST* init(int data){
    BST* a = new BST;
    a->data = data;
    a->right = NULL;
    a->left = NULL;
    return a;
}

BST* insert(BST* root, int data){
    if (root == NULL)
        root = new BST;
    else{
        BST* current = root;
        if (current->data >= data)
            insert(current->right, data);
        else
            insert(current->left, data);
    }
    return 0;
}

void inorderTraversal(BST* root)
{
    cout << "seg fault here" << endl;
    if(root == NULL) 
        cout << "No node" << endl;
    inorderTraversal(root->left);
    cout << root->data << endl;
    inorderTraversal(root->right);
}


int main(){
    BST* tree = init(5);
    int a[8] = {1, 3, 5, 6, 3, 9, 10, 46};
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(int); i++)
        insert(tree, a[i]);
    inorderTraversal(tree);
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to pinpoint your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint, if you're still debugging:

Both children of a leaf node are `NULL`, which you correctly set via your `init()` method. However, when you create a new node, you aren't consistent in using `init()`.

Also, you may want to step through/put `cout`s in your `insert()` method so that you can watch it build the tree.